# Acceleration during a car crash

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A car in a crash test decelerates from $20ms^{-1}$ to a stop over a period of $0.6 s$. The crash dummy's mass is $75kg $. Find the acceleration of the car during this time.

Hint - it is a negative acceleration.

Please help me, I am struggling.

Comment: I cannot actually see a question to answer? Maybe give some more information.

Comment: That's a homework like problem , but mind using $v^2=u^2+2as$ ?

Comment: what about F= ma ???? @NehalSamee

Comment: This shows no effort.

Comment: @Annascott ... That's what you use to find force ...

Answer (score 1):

Here we should use these two formulae to get the result easily:
$$v_2^2-v_1^2=2ax \hspace{1cm}, x=1/2at^2+v_1t+x_0$$ that here we have:
$$v_1=20 ms^{-1}, v_2=0, t=0.6s , x_0=0$$

In this case, if you substitute these quantities you'll get $a=0$!
Something is wrong!

However, I think something is missing here, like friction coefficient. That's why you have the mass in the assumption!
You need to check the question more carefully.

Comment: But no $x$ is given ... So first and  second formula is inappropriate here ... Rather , $v=u+at$ will work ...